# Redirect authenticated and guest users in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-authentication

I'm new with Laravel, and my web application consists of 3 types of users (guards): Admins, Agents, Players.
Authentication is working fine with Admins and Agents, since they shouldn't be able to see their dashboard unless they are logged in.

The problem with Players, which can access all the pages in the website as guests and when they login the only change is in the navigation bar.

I'm getting the following error:

**Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.**

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
public const HOME = '/';
public const LOGGEDIN = '/loggedin';
public const AGENT = '/agent';
public const ADMIN = '/admin';
```

**web.php**

```
 
 Route::group(['namespace' => 'Front','middleware' => 'guest:player', 'middleware' => 'auth:player'], function(){

   Route::get('/','FrontController@index')-> name('front.home');
   Route::get('loggedin','FrontController@index')-> name('front.loggedin');
   Route::get('Page1','FrontController@get_page1')-> name('front.page1');
   Route::get('Page2','FrontController@get_page2')-> name('front.page2');
   Route::get('logout','FrontController@logout')-> name('front.logout');
});
```

**Authenticate.php**

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        $current_req = request()->segment(count(request()->segments()));
        if($current_req == 'admin'){
            return route('admin.login');
        }
        elseif($current_req == 'agent'){
            return route('agent.login');
        }
        elseif($current_req == ''){
            return route('front.home');
        }
        else{
            return route('front.home');
        }
}}
```

**RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
       
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            if($guard == 'agent')
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::AGENT);
            elseif($guard == 'admin')
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN);
            elseif($guard == 'player'){
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::LOGGEDIN);
            }
            else
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `return redirect()->route('admin.login');` and so on instead?

Comment: @Savlon Thanks for your reply, do you mean within Authenticate class?